# sqlite3 echo and '<' piping command not working as expected

Tags: sql, bash, ubuntu, sqlite

I am reading a [SQL book](http://sql.learncodethehardway.org/) and the author is using Sqlite3, which is awesome because there is not a server to mess with.

In the book the author says to type:

`sqlite3 -echo something.db < some.sql`

The problem is nothing ever echos out to the terminal nor is there even a database created from the '<' redirection command.

Does anyone know what is going on...with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the command you show IS a proper way of creating a new database from sql dump.

Can you please show your sql file contents (`cat some.sql`)? The only way I can reproduce the behavior described is by feeding sqlite an empty sql file.

Try this commands and see if you can get the same result:

```
$ cat <<EOF > test.sql
> create table test1 (f1, f2, f3);
> insert into test1(f1, f2, f3) values ("foo", "bar", "baz");
> EOF
$ sqlite3 -echo test.db < test.sql
create table test1 (f1, f2, f3);
insert into test1(f1, f2, f3) values ("foo", "bar", "baz");
$ file test.db
test.db: SQLite 3.x database
```

Comment: hi. i can dump the sql to a .txt or something otherwise it looks like insane byte code. let me work on this a minute.I am going to try your bash-foo now also! :D

Comment: I was able to obtain the same results! That is awesome.

Comment: Please find my SQL dump: `PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE person(id integer primary key, first_name text, last_name text, age integer);
INSERT INTO "person" VALUES(0,'beta','bill',59);
CREATE TABLE pet(id integer primary key, name text, breed text, age integer, dead integer);
INSERT INTO "pet" VALUES(0,'t.rex','dinosaur',23,0);
CREATE TABLE person_pet(person_id integer, pet_id integer);
INSERT INTO "person_pet" VALUES(0,0);
COMMIT;`

Comment: i used the .output and .dump meta sqlite3 commands for this dump

Comment: maybe your example works because you do not create the .sql file through sqlite3 but in the terminal... this is what I am thinking. I went ahead and selected yours as the correct answer because it does echo and do everything as you wrote it. thank-you for your help and everyone else, especially @N1xx1 :D That's a rap guys. Hats off.

Answer (score 0):

`something.db` is an existing database. `< some.sql` means it picks data from that file and write it in the sqlite console. So both files have to exist.

`something.db` must be a valid l sqlite3 database file (or an empty or not existing file); `some.sql` must be a text file with your commands in it.

The `-echo` params specify that it have to print the command before execution.

Comment: This makes me think about a lot of things. Thank-you for the reply. Is there a way to create an empty database .db file then load the existing .sql file into it? Because if I create a new database I have to specify a new table and stuff or it just disappears when i exit sqlite3...

Comment: @user If the database.db exists the query in some.sql will just edit it.

Comment: do i need to create tables for the database.db to load a .sql file into it?

Comment: @user as the user above replied, it's a proper way to execute an sql dump. You can either use it on an existing database or not existing, you can either create tables or just put some INSERT or UPDATE, you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: when i do the command i do not see everything echo'd in the same way.I see some SQL statements garbled together then the directory location and bash dollar sign :/

Comment: in the output shown above through the hyperlink, the database does not exist but the sql file does...

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments and your terminal screen shot, I get the impression that your "some.sql" file may be in the wrong encoding and/or starts with a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) which confuses sqlite.

You can use the `file` command to find out, and if this is the problem use `iconv`, `recode` or your favorite text editor to convert the file into the encoding your terminal expects, and the correct line endings (`\n` aka "LF" in Linux, `\r\n` aka "CRLF" in Windows).